# Fineuploader Chunking not working for Signature Version 4

Tags: php, fine-uploader

I have copied the endpoint PHP code to our side and tried to change the signature version. All things are working expect Chunking with signature 4. I am not able to find the value for $expectedHostName variable. Can you help me for this?

Console Logs

```
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Parsing template
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Template parsing complete
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Attempting to update thumbnail based on server response.
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Attempting to update thumbnail based on server response.
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Rendering template in DOM.
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Template rendering complete
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Received 1 files.
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Attempting to validate image.
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Generating new thumbnail for 0
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Attempting to draw client-side image preview.
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Attempting to determine if Shree.rar can be rendered in this browser
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] First pass: check type attribute of blob object.
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Shree.rar is not previewable in this browser per the blob's type attr
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Not previewable
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 1-5242880 of 11375841
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 5242881-10485760 of 11375841
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 10485761-11375841 of 11375841
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Submitting S3 signature request for 0
s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Sending POST request for 0

[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Submitting S3 initiate multipart upload request for 0 s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)
[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Sending POST request for 0 s3.jque...ader.js (line 251)

[Fine Uploader 5.4.1] Chunked upload request failed for 0, chunk 2
```

Encryption version 2 is working fine with single upload and chunked upload.
Encryption version 4 is not working with chunking. Normal uploading is working fine.

Headers

```
Accept  
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Authorization   
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAIHBOOHQJ2XNTRNVA/20151217/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=host
;x-amz-acl;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-meta-qqfilename,Signature=a3191364d9b4a4ba838b9ff01e8f83a1d6b2d6676556a782522c85ebdfe4b1ef
DNT 1
Host    s3.amazonaws.com
Origin  http://local.example.com
Referer http://local.example.com/aws_outer_file_transfer/upload?b=wJ5qhvk-ZjT2DPR32cNhGMZFLjryoFnKSEdks7NUIa0&p=pkoOAVk2Gsl1yWFadqQnDRa2LB58cHVJgXKdHxfOvjs&f=gcbMIEgl7niRXfYET6ei8MVysgHBjWZjLVQRDOQRBDA&b=wJ5qhvk-ZjT2DPR32cNhGMZFLjryoFnKSEdks7NUIa0
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
x-amz-acl   private
x-amz-content-sha256    e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
x-amz-date  20151217T120731Z
x-amz-meta-qqfilename   Shree.rar
```

Signature is creating fine. But when request sending to AWS
like - https://s3.amazonaws.com//New%20Test%20Folder%202/Testing%20Loader%203/Shree.rar?uploads

Getting Error Message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match
 the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

Comment: Contrary to what you have said in your question, it doesn't look like version 4 signatures are working for you at all. The `$expectedHostName` is not your problem, there is a deeper issue. You'll need to provide much more information such as: what requests are failing, what is unique about these requests, etc.

Comment: Hey! Please check my question again. Please help me for correct this.

Comment: Probably an issue with some of the settings in your PHP code. There are a number of options that you must provide via environment variables. What values did you provide? Also, what does the response to Fine Uploader's signature requests look like?